# ngFor change the bgcolor of the item that i click in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to change background color of the button that i click, below is my code, But, it is not running as i expected,instead it is changing all the row buttons. Any help?

```
<tr *ngFor="let stageitem of stageListData">
        <td>{{stageitem.srcScriptInstanceName}}</td>
        <td>{{stageitem.startTime}}</td>
        <td>{{stageitem.endTime}}</td>
        <td>Manual</td>
        <td>{{stageitem.state}}</td>
        <td><button class="erroDisplayBtn" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':btnColor}" (click)="errorStepMenuOpen($event, stageitem)">{{stageitem.error}}</button></td>
</tr>
```

Angular 2 script

```
 errorStepMenuOpen() {
    this.errorStepMenu = true;
    this.btnColor = "#ff7300";
 }
```

Comment: It will change all rows button color, because of your variable `this. btnColor` is changing which same for all.

Comment: You have nothing there referring to which stageitem you mean, so of course it doesn't work. Set something on *that specific object*, use the index of the item, or break out a child component with its own state.

Comment: `this` probably refers to the component object, so it's global with respect to your repeated elements.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your question as I was going through the same challenge but in my case Im trying to change the color of an svg icon after I click its table-row where it lives.  Here is how I solved mine.

```js
 <tr *ngFor="let item of someList; let i = index" (click)="changeColor(i, item)">
                                    
        <span [style.background-color]="item.name !== selectedName ? 'red' : 'blue'">
            <i-check-square>
        </span>
</tr>
```

Then on my ts file:

```js
 selectedName:any;

 ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedName = null;
    }
changColor(i, item) {
        if ((this.selectedName = item.supplierName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround is instead of having a single `btnColor`, you can have a `btnColors` array.

On `stageListData` populated, you can loop through `stageListData` then for each stageItem, push a default color to `btnColors`.

In your template, make follow changes:

```
<tr *ngFor="let stageitem of stageListData; let i = index;">
     <td>{{stageitem.srcScriptInstanceName}}</td>
     <td>{{stageitem.startTime}}</td>
     <td>{{stageitem.endTime}}</td>
     <td>Manual</td>
     <td>{{stageitem.state}}</td>
     <td><button class="erroDisplayBtn" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':btnColor[i]}" (click)="errorStepMenuOpen($event, stageitem, i)">{{stageitem.error}}</button></td>
</tr>
```

In your ts:

```
errorStepMenuOpen(event, stageItem, index) {
    this.errorStepMenu = true;
    this.btnColors[index] = "#ff7300";
}
```